# Searching with multiple select boxes

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to make a query having multiple select boxes, User can select one or multiple values from the drop down menu, But its not working it works only if user select one select box if user tries to select two or more select box values it is not able to display the where clause properly. I saw this code in another web site but not able to pick it properly, If some one can help in understanding or simplifying...

```
if ($office != '') {    
    $where = ($where == '') ? 'WHERE ' : 'AND ';
    $where .= "adpno = '$office'";
}

if ($sector!= '') { 
    $where = ($where == '') ? 'WHERE ' : 'AND ';
    $where .= "sector= '$sector'";
}

if ($subsector!= '') {  
    $where = ($where == '') ? 'WHERE ' : 'AND ';
    $where .= "subsector= '$subsector'";
}

mysql_query('SELECT * FROM sometable ' . $where);
```

Comment: It always helps to do an `echo` or `var_dump` of your `$where` to see how your query really looks.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to add a space before and after `AND` and `WHERE`!

In your code when more than one condition is used, the query is probably built as: `SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE subsector=3AND sector=5` (note the lack of space before `AND`).

In your code sample, there is a space only after `AND/WHERE`. Note that MySQL ignores whitespaces in the query, so don't worry if it ends up with a double space sometimes. Just make sure to have at least one space, separating all elements of the query.

EDIT: Also, make sure that each `if` concatenates to the previous `WHERE` clause instead of overwriting it. So:

```
if ($office != '') {    
    $where .= ($where == '') ? ' WHERE ' : ' AND ';
    $where .= "adpno = '$office'";
}

if ($sector!= '') { 
    $where .= ($where == '') ? ' WHERE ' : ' AND ';
    $where .= "sector= '$sector'";
}

if ($subsector!= '') {  
    $where .= ($where == '') ? ' WHERE ' : ' AND ';
    $where .= "subsector= '$subsector'";
}

mysql_query('SELECT * FROM sometable ' . $where);
```

Comment: No its not like what you are saying actually i am printing the query if you select values from two or three select boxes it only displays the last value selected. Where clause is overwritten by the and clause. In short its not concatenating

Answer (score 0):

```
$fields = array('sector' , 'subsector' , 'office');
$query = '';
foreach($fields as $field)
{
 if($query != '')
   $query .= ' AND ';
 if( $input[$field] != '')
   $query .= $field ." = '". $input[$field] ."'";
}
```

I would recommend you to use mysqli or pdo instead of mysql.
`$input` is an array of the input values after you've made "security checks",
for instance: `mysql_escape_string` and `htmlspecialchars`

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like this:

```
$conditions = '';

if ($tmp = @$_GET['office'])
    $conditions .= ($conditions != '' ? ' AND ' : '') . 'office = \'' . mysql_escape_string($tmp) . '\'';
if ($tmp = @$_GET['sector'])
    $conditions .= ($conditions != '' ? ' AND ' : '') . 'sector = \'' . mysql_escape_string($tmp) . '\'';
// ...

mysql_query('SELECT * FROM sometable' . ($conditions != '' ? ' WHERE ' . $conditions : '') . 'M');
```

If you've got more than just two or three fields, a foreach loop might be better suited:

```
$conditions = '';
$fields = array('office', 'sector', 'subsector', /*...*/);

foreach ($fields as $field)
    if ($tmp = @$_GET[$field])
        $conditions .= ($conditions != '' ? ' AND ' : '') . $field . ' = \'' . mysql_escape_string($tmp) . '\'';

mysql_query('SELECT * FROM sometable' . ($conditions != '' ? ' WHERE ' . $conditions : '') . 'M');
```

You could even simplify code a bit by always having at least one condition (untested, but should work):

```
$conditions = 'TRUE';
$fields = array('office', 'sector', 'subsector', /*...*/);

foreach ($fields as $field)
    if ($tmp = @$_GET[$field])
        $conditions .= ' AND ' . $field . ' = \'' . mysql_escape_string($tmp) . '\'';

mysql_query('SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE ' . $conditions . ';'));
```

Comment: It worked but still having problem, I am having one date column in database, Where as in UI i am having two select boxes one for month and the other for years. Now the problem is that i am not able to give specific condition, i.e concatenating month and year in where caluse..

Comment: You could just append one more condition using the template I've used in the first code snippet, just using those two fields at once.

Comment: Also considering this sounds like a new issue, you should add that in a separate question adding more details, like "How to calculate a date and look for it in a SQL table?" or something like that, considering none of these details are in your initial question.